# Integrating $\sqrt\frac{x}{{x+a}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I integrate this expression?
$$\sqrt\frac{x}{{x+a}}$$

I substituted $x=a\tan^2t$. After substituting, I reach
$$\int \sec x\tan^2x$$
Is this way correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Substitute $u = x+a$ instead.  Your variables aren't squared, so your substitution doesn't work.

Comment: Does substitution only works when the variables are squared? Thanks.

Comment: What is the derivative of tan x?

Comment: Thanks everyone! But I edited the question now. It was incorrect before.

Comment: Do you want to calculate $\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+a}}dx$ or $\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}dx$ ?

Comment: The latter. Actually I made a mistake previously. Please bear with me I am new to mathstack.

Comment: Ok I just edited your question. is it correct now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for editing.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385274/integral-of-int-sqrt-fracxx1dx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Natasha J, here is your new answer!
Let $$t=\dfrac{x}{x+a}, \ \dfrac{at}{(1-t)}=x$$

$$\int \sqrt{\dfrac{x}{x+a}}dx=a\int \sqrt{t}\dfrac{1(1-t)-(-1)t}{(1-t)^2}dt$$
$$=a\int\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{(1-t)^2}dt$$
by uv-substitution
$$=\dfrac{a\sqrt{t}}{1-t}-\dfrac{a}{2}\int \dfrac{1}{(1-t)\sqrt{t}}dt$$ where the left side integral is, with $t=u^2$ $$-\dfrac{a}{2}\int \dfrac{1}{1-u}+\dfrac{1}{1+u}du=-\dfrac{a}{2}\left(\ln|1+u|-\ln|1-u|\right)+C$$

which gives

$$\boxed{\int\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{x+a}}dx=\sqrt{x+a}\sqrt{x}-\dfrac{a}{2}\ln\dfrac{|\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x}|}{|\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}|}+C}$$ Also,

$$0=\lim_{a\to 0}\dfrac{a}{2}\ln\dfrac{|\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x}|}{|\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}|}$$

It was simpler than it seemed. Using similar steps,

$$\int \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}}dx$$ can be known.

Comment: Thank you! It is informative.  I edited the question though. It was incorrect before. Can you help me?

Comment: @NatashaJ I have your answer!

Answer (score 2):

One method is to just substitute
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}}$$
that is $$ x = \frac{at^2}{t^2-1}$$
$$ dx = \frac{-2at}{(t^2-1)^2} dt $$
We get
$$ \int \sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}} dx = \int \frac{-2at^2}{(t^2-1)^2} dt$$
This is an integral of a rational function and can be solved using standard methods.

Another method is to use substitution given by the condition
$$ \sqrt{x^2+ax} = u-x$$
which can be solved to get
$$ x = \frac{u^2}{2u+a}$$
$$ \sqrt{x^2+ax} = \frac{u(u+a)}{2u+a}$$
$$ dx = \frac{2u(u+a)}{(2u+a)^2}dt $$
We get then
$$ \int \sqrt{\frac{x}{x+a}} dx  = \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}} dx = \int \frac{2u^2}{(2u+a)^2}du $$
which also can be solved using standard methods.

These substitutions are special cases of so-called [Euler subsitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).

Comment: Thank you! I am going to search Euler substitution now!

Comment: I enjoyed this answer, you should know.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer to your exact question. YES!, it is correct. The substitution transform your integral to $$2a\displaystyle\int \sec x\tan^2x\, dx.$$ Then you can simplify it further using the fact that $\sec x\tan^2x=\sec^3x-\sec x.$ Powers of secant is quit different from [other integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928303/express-an-integral-in-terms-of-another-integral/3931703#3931703) if that format, but can integrate using a reduction formula. First let $$I_n=\displaystyle\int \sec^nx\, dx,$$ then $I_0=x,\quad I_1=\ln|\sec x+\tan x|$ and $I_2=\tan x$ are the simplest known cases up to constants. For $n\ge 2$ use integration by parts with $u=\sec^{n-2}x$ and $dv=\sec^2x dx$ to get $$I_n=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x-(n-2)\displaystyle\int \sec^{n-2}x\tan^2 x\, dx.$$ Since $\tan^2 x=\sec^2x-1,$ we get a simplified recursive formula $$I_n=\dfrac{\sec^{n-2}x\tan x}{n-1}-\left(\dfrac{n-2}{n-1}\right)I_{n-2}.$$ Hope you can get your solution from here :).

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me! I tried that way and now as you say, it is correct but the answer in the book was given in different format, which confused me. Is it all right if this happens, that is your substitution is correct, yet your answers don't have the same format. Because it makes it looks like the integral has two different answers!

Comment: @NatashaJ: These are definite integral. So they can have answers  different up to a constant. For example $$2\int \sec^2 x\tan x\, dx$$ is either $\sec^2 x+C$ or $\tan^2x+C'$ depending on your substitution. But since $\sec^2 x=\tan^2x+1,$ they are equal up to a constant. This might be the case with your text book solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing!

Comment: @NatashaJ: Great. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the substitution $x=a\sinh^2t$ is more convenient:

$$\int\sqrt\frac{x}{{x+a}}dx
=a\int 2\sinh^2tdt
= \frac a2\sinh2t-at+C
$$

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, it is more convenient. Thanks again

Comment: This is not correct; at $a=0$, the integral is $x$ but the result of yours is $0$.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad - it is not 0 because $t$ depends on $a$

Comment: @Quanto, I am aware of this and as $a\to 0$ $\sqrt{x/(x+a)}\to 1$, which leaves $-at\to 0, 0.5a\sinh(2t)\to 0$. Also, the graphs of the integral and your result do not match.

Comment: @Quantico here it is: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/djtcoz5cz2.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad - you graphed the incorrect function

Comment: @Quantico Oops...https://www.desmos.com/calculator/unbsfbdliy